# How can I acquire or create a replacement latch for my service panel?

Tags: electrical-panel, lock, usa

(I apologize if this seems like a shopping question - but I am out of ideas right now)

The black plastic, flat handle of the door to my domestic electrical box snapped off and I stupidly threw it away instead of keeping it and trying to glue it back together.

Based on the make and model of the panel I have been searching on the internet and the only matching latches I can find are large brass, keyed locks suitable for a more commercial setting.  I asked my electrician and he couldn't come up with one either (including from stuff he had lying around).

What can I do to to provide a latch for this electrical box, that would satisfy electrical code?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure there's any Code requirement to have that door latch shut. However it also looks like there's a knockout to fit a proper latch mechanism that is lockable. What do you think ThreePhaseEel?

Comment: @Harper I believe that knockout is for use by the large, brass locks I have found online.  However I am trying to stay the original subtle in my domestic situation.  The sort of lock I have seen would stick out like a sore thumb.  And as for no lock, while not an issue for me I am concerned what the people might think

Comment: No, I doubt it's for generic locks.  Latches tend to be particular to each manufacturer.  Siemens acquired the ITE line.  I do see [this online](https://www.stateelectric.com/products/siemens-ecqfl1/) but yeah, it's a brute and I can't say it fits your panel.

Comment: @Harper Yeah that looks like what I have previously seen.

Comment: Have you checked the Siemens parts catalog at https://w3.usa.siemens.com/powerdistribution/us/en/speedfax-product-catalog/Documents/2017/SF-17-Sect-01-ALL-web.pdf  ?   They have a part named ECSIELATCH that might be the right one.

Comment: That Siemens part number is the right one. They haven't changed the design of the old ITE load centers in 30+ years, other than having the Siemens name cast into the plastic. But there is no requirement to have a latch, or even a door, so it's OK to make something on your own, like a little cabinet pull or something.

Comment: @Harper -- indeed, the latch is not a Code requirement (nor is the door, even).  ECSIELATCH should be the right part.

Comment: @whiskeychief Put that in an answer, I think you'll get some upvotes.

Comment: @J.Raefield I'm about to sell this house and while there may be no code requirement for a latch, all it takes is an overzealous inspector and I am suddenly running around trying to solve this issue.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I'm not conversant in electrical code at all, but I would be surprised to learn that that there is no requirement for a door especially in a residential location with the possibility of children running amok.

Comment: The National Electric Code is primarily about fire safety; the official name of it is  NFPA Standard 79, for National Fire Protection Agency. A door on the front does not change the fire safety aspect of a load center, likewise a latch on that door. It's the job of parents to keep their kids out of the breaker panel, just like it's your job to keep them from putting a knife into the socket...

A Home Inspector is not a legal authority, you can simply say "I'm not going to fix trivial things that are not code violations". I do.

Comment: @J.Raefield 70, not 79 :) but yes -- the *deadfront* on the panel keeps the wandering fingers away from the live bits, door or no door

Comment: Oops, yep NFPA 70, my finger slipped...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution was a small piece of stick on velcro that secured the door when it was closed, and then released the door with a small tug.  As it was placed on the inside of the door it was not noticeable when the door was closed, and it was also thin enough that the door looked properly closed.

Answer (score 2):

### Get an ECSIELATCH

While the NEC does not even require a door to begin with on a NEMA 1 (indoor) loadcenter/panelboard (some small loadcenters do not have one to begin with!), never mind a functioning latch or lock on said door, this is pretty easy to fix if you so desire.  The I-T-E line of residential electrical equipment was acquired by Siemens (and hasn't changed all that much since then), so I would try fitting a Siemens ECSIELATCH there (it's the replacement latch specified for current Siemens panels by their [repair parts guide](https://www.downloads.siemens.com/download-center/Download.aspx?pos=download&fct=getasset&id1=BTLV_47493) and also for the G4040B1200 by their [cross-reference guide (warning: Excel spreadsheet)](https://www.siemens.com/download?BTLV_39167)).

If you can't find one, a supply house that carries Siemens products should darn well either have it or be able to order it in; barring that, Allied Electronics, of all folks, [has them in stock](https://www.alliedelec.com/product/siemens/ecsielatch/70820980/) at the time of this writing.

Comment: The minimum order quantity is 25 pieces (I used to work for Siemens), so you need to just buy it from someone who has them in stock.

Comment: I went and ordered one from Allied.  $1.36 for the part and $6 for the cheapest shipping!

Comment: I received the ECSIELATCH yesterday and and in no way is it a replacement part for my panel - even if I popped out the breakout section of the door :-(

Comment: @PeterM -- that's odd!  *wonders when the design got changed...*